# NGINX liip_imagine unable to create path for ... "Get operation failed" webp - not creating .webp in media/cache/filter_name symfony

Tags: nginx, php7, imagemagick, images, symfony

So in my liip_imagine i have something like:

```
webp:
  generate: True
  quality: 70
```

and it works good locally, it serves .png.webp images, but when i put it on my NGINX server i have an issue called
unable to create path for ... "Get operation failed, im using imagick as a driver. I have webp in mime types on my server. The problem is that it shows error also on imagick like

```
    if (isset($options['format'])) {
          $this->imagick>setimageformat($options['format']);
     }
```

It doesnt recognize the format, but i don't know how could i debug it to see what format is given, i tried dump($options['format']) but it doesnt show anything anywhere.
How can i solve this problem? Should i use other way to create webp on my server? Why does it work locally ok, but on server not.

Comment: show us some error logs, show us the permissions of the directory

Comment: the problem was that imagick on server didnt support webp format, i had to update imagick

Comment: please answer your questions and accept the answer